# Umbraco xslt count filtered pages

Tags: xslt, filter, umbraco, counter

Needs some help. In umbraco I have my tree like this

```
-First
  - page 1
  - page 2
  - page 3
  - page 4
  - page 5
  - page 6
  - page 7
  - page 8
  - page 9
  - page 10
  - page 11
  - page 12...
```

looping all the pages i filter them.
So I apply my xslt only to pages 4,7,10
position() will give me 4,7,10
How can I count the number of pages i walked through? (in this example 3)
Here's my xslt:

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc][last()]"/>
<xsl:variable name="articles" select="$root/descendant-or-self::* [@isDoc][@level=2]"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$articles">
    <xsl:if test="./* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='myfilteredpage']">
       ...some html construction...
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for your help.
Benjamin

PS: found those link that helped me to build the pagination but my counter isn't resolved

[first link](http://www.nibble.be/?p=11)

[second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440908/how-to-make-pagination-in-xslt)

Comment: Your qustion and provided stuffs are not clear. Please put some more stuffs to understand clearly.

Comment: Thank you Navin for your answer I've edited and add a new post...

Comment: Hi @NavinRawat did you see the new comments and answers??

Answer (score 0):

you can count the total number of pages you walk through like this:

```
count($articles/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='myfilteredpage'])
```

If you would like to have current 'count' inside your loop, you should change your xsl like this:

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc][last()]"/>
<xsl:variable name="articles" select="$root/descendant-or-self::* [@isDoc][@level=2]"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="articlesToLoop" select="$articles//* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='myfilteredpage']" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$articlesToLoop">
    Current count: <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> 
    - <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i'll try it now. Just a technical question: what is the difference between 1 slash **$articles/...** and 2 slashes **$articles//...** ?

Comment: one slash will only include child nodes, 2 slashes includes all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.)

Comment: Hi @JasperSteenweg, have you any other help for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the counter you give... The counter show 0 when it needs to show 2.
I've found another behaviour of my xsl that is not clear. Only when my page as at least 1 child publish it shows me the page.
Here is my xslt code

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc][last()]"/>
<xsl:variable name="articles" select="$root/descendant::* [@isDoc][@level=2]"/>
<xsl:variable name="NumberOfCharactersToShow" select="number(400)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- start writing XSLT -->
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="count($articles//* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='Article'])" />
<xsl:value-of select="$counter" />
<xsl:for-each select="$articles">
    <xsl:variable name="article" select="* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='Article']" />
    <xsl:if test="$article">
        <xsl:call-template name="article" />
        <!--<xsl:for-each select="current()/descendant::* [@isDoc]">
            <xsl:call-template name="article" />
        </xsl:for-each>-->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="article">
<xsl:variable name="text" select="umbraco.library:StripHtml(umbraco.library:TruncateString(bodyText,$NumberOfCharactersToShow,'...'))"/>
<!--article-->
<div class="article border border-radius border-shadow">
    <div class="atitle">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="title" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="atext">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$text" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Try to explain. Here is my example tree

```
-first page
  -page
  -article1 (published)
    -article2 (unpublished)
    -article3 (unpublished)
  -page
  -page
  -page
  -article4 (published)
  -page
  -article5 (published)
    -article6 (published)
    -article7 (unpublished)
  -page...
```

actually my code will create only article5 (the children (article6,7) creation is in xslt comments)
But as you can see article1 and article4 are not created...I don't understand why...

Thanks for your help.
Benjamin

Comment: It's probably because you only select articles that 'live' on level 2 (<xsl:variable name="articles" select="$root/descendant::* [@isDoc][@level=2]"/>)

Comment: Hi, Searching for the solution i conclude that my problem is the current(). Because i'm not in a for-each so current() is unknown. and using $currentPage is also irrelevant cause it will refered to the first page in the Level.

Comment: level=2 is in my umbraco the level of page and articles I've shown you here.

Comment: This variable: <xsl:variable name="articles" select="$root/descendant::* [@isDoc][@level=2]"/> will only hold the articles on level 2 (article 1, 4 and 5). In the for-each loop you're looping these nodes, but only displaying these nodes if the has a published article as child: * [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide)!='1' and local-name(current())='Article']. In the for-each loop the current() is a node of the initial $articles list, thus only nodes of level 2. If you can provide the umbraco.config xml (in app_data folder) i can write an xslt for you

Comment: Thank you Jasper for your answer. It is my logic to go over articles on level2 and do to thing: 1) create it in html 2)check if they have childs (only articles can be childs of an article). and to create the childs html. But more than that i need to create a pagination. and for that i need to have a variable that contains the number of Articles in level 2 and their childs. For the umbraco.config xml i'll ask if i can give you it...

Comment: @JasperSteenweg can you be more specific about what you want to see in umbraco.config xml?? How is it relevant to build the xslt?? Thank you for your precious help

Comment: you could rebuild your problem here: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/XZioD4/2 so we can make changes online.